# Jquery Graph Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a simple graph like the picture below. For instance if you specify the value is 50 % , It would cover 50% of the rectangle box . I can't seem to figure out a way to approach the coding ? Can someone please kindly help me ? :)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the width of a `<div>` to be a percentage.

**HTML**

```
<div class="percentage-box-wrapper">
  <div class="percentage-box" id="percentage-box-1"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.percentage-box-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 18px;
  width: 160px;
}

.percentage-box {
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function setBox1Percentage(percent) {
  document.getElementById('percentage-box-1').style.width = percent + '%';
}

setBox1Percentage(60);
```

Take a look at this working [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/yAAdM/).

The above code is a custom way of doing what you want. However, if you do not want to re-invent the wheel, you can look into using jQuery UI's [`Progressbar`](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) widget.

Comment: @Uncle Toby - No problem :) Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HTML5 native progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) element instead.